# Final Permissions User Interface Changed in API 23

Tags: android, api, permissions

As they say in :

http://android-developers.blogspot.com.tr/2015/08/m-developer-preview-3-final-sdk.html

Android Platform Change:

Final Permissions User Interface — we updated the permissions user interface and enhanced some of the permissions behavior.

What is the difference now in Permissions from the old API ?

Comment: If by "old API" you mean "API-22", then read about **runtime permission** in Android 6.0: https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#behavior-runtime-permissions and https://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New in Marshmallow: [Runtime Permissions](https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#behavior-runtime-permissions)

[Runtime Permissions explained (Preview)](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html)

Your question is most likely about the UI presented upon [Activity.requestPermissions()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#requestPermissions(java.lang.String[],%20int)).

Looks like Google, with Preview 3 and final SDK has finished the UI for that :)